# How does java resolve hidden methods at runtime

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers, overriding

Given the following class hierarchy

```
package pack1;

public class A
{
    private int methodOne(int i)
    {
        return ++i;
    }

    public int methodTwo(int i)
    {
        return methodOne(++i);
    }
}

package pack2;

import pack1.A;

class B extends A
{
    int methodOne(int i)
    {
        return methodTwo(++i);
    }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new B().methodOne(101));
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is **104**.  `Class B`creates its own version of `methodOn()` because `methodOne()` is `private` in `Class A`.  However, during runtime, when inside `methodTwo()`, the runtime object is of type `Class B`.  Why would `java` use the `methodOne()` in `class A` as oppose of `class B`.

Comment: you may approve one answer as a correct answer which suits to your question exactly by marking Tick on answer. Marking Tick means its a verified answer approved by the asked User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, despite the name, *the two methods are entirely different*. `methodOne` in class `B` does not override the method with the same name in class `A`. As you said, `B` can't see the private `methodOne`, so it can't possibly override it. So Java creates two separate methods that are not related in any way. Then `A`'s `methodTwo` calls the `methodOne` that's defined in `A`. If it were public or protected, then other classes might have overridden it, resulting in the late binding we know all too well from Java. However, the `methodOne` that it sees has never been overridden because `B` didn't know to do so.

**tl;dr**: Internally, they're two different and unrelated methods, even though the names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

At very first your code starts executing the code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(new B().methodOne(101)); // it invokes methodOne() of class B.
    }
```

Above code calls `methodOne()` of `class B`. Now, `MethodOne()` is private so it won't override in `Class B`

Now definition of `methodOne()` in Class B

```
int methodOne(int i)
    {
        return methodTwo(++i);  // calling methodTwo() from class A which is a super class of class B.
    }
```

this code is increase the value of `i` by 1. So, Now `i = 102`. Now again the methodTwo calling the `methodOne()` of `class B` in below code.

```
public int methodTwo(int i) //methodTwo in class A. part of object due to public access modifier.
    {
        return methodOne(++i); // it increase the value of i by 1. Now i =103.
    }
```

Now the value of `i = 103`. Now it calls `methodOne()` of `class A` , because `methodOne()` is private in `Class A`

```
private int methodOne(int i)
    {
        return ++i; //again this increase the value of i by 1. Now i =104.
    }
```

increased the value of `i` by 1. So, variable `i = 104`. So, Final value of `i` is 104 Now.

> So, The Final Output is 104.